# Appium driver null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, appium

I am new to Appium and just getting started, I have been following an example and using a basic Contacts apk on Android tablet to start against. The code I have is pretty much copied from the example I am following but when I try to run the test I get a null pointer exception. I did some debugging and find that the driver = null is why I am getting this exception. I looked around and found some code that I thought might help but it hasn't.

The code I have is

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class addContact {

    AppiumDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp () throws Exception {

        new DesiredCapabilities();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
           capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"AndroidTestDevice");

        try
        {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("URL init error");
        }

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown () throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void addNewContact (){


     System.out.println (driver);
     WebElement addContactButton = driver.findElementById("com.example.android.contactmanager:id/addContactButton");
     addContactButton.click();
    }

}`
```

The exception I get is :

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at addContact.addNewContact(addContact.java:49)
> ```

and the line this occurs in is :

```
WebElement addContactButton = driver.findElementById("com.example.android.contactmanager:id/addContactButton");
```

Comment: Is your setUp  correctly called, and doesn't give a "URL init error" ?

Comment: Impossible to say why it's null from this code... There are many possibilities: `setUp()` isn't called (or is called pmöy after calling `addNewContact()`, not before), an Exception occured in the AppiumDriver constructor, etc....

Comment: I thought setUp was always called first since its tagged @Before? Is that not the case? If not, that would certainly explain the problem I have but how do I force the setUp to execute first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null Pointer Exception Being returned - Java Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493161/null-pointer-exception-being-returned-java-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it showing as null pointer because you are using "testng" annotation for "Tests" and "junit" annotation for "Before and after". Change `import org.testng.annotations.Test;` to `import org.junit.Test;` and run it as junit test.

This should work, just tested it on my side.

Comment: Ahhhh... Thanks so much Gaurav!