# Null Pointer Exception Being returned - Java Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Getting Null Pointer exception when running test in Selenium WebDriver with Java. For some reason the test is retunrning null, even everything is being declared correctly (I think?).

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

//Given this code:

````
public class HomePage extends DriverSetup{

    @FindBy(className = "ico fa fa-lock")
    static WebElement loginButton;

    public HomePage (WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }


  public static void logInBut(){
        loginButton.click();
  }```



//When running this test:


```public class test1 extends DriverSetup{

    public test1() {
        super(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void signIn(){

        getDriver().get(URL);

        HomePage.logInBut();

        logInPage.inEmail(" ");
        logInPage.inPassword(" ");


    }```


//Driver Set up:

```public class DriverSetup {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public DriverSetup(WebDriver driver) {
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        if(this.driver == null) {
            this.setUp();
        }
        return this.driver;
    }

    public void FindByInitialization (WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    //Set up Driver
    @BeforeClass //Before executing any test in the class do this
    public static void setUp(){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Peter.Redondeiro\\Documents" +
        "\\IDEA projects\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.EXE");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); //maximise window when open
    }

    //clear all the cookies after executing each test
    @After
    public void clearCookies(){
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); //delete all the cookies
    }

    //Close browser after executing all the tests in the class
    @AfterClass
    public static void closeBrowser(){
        driver.close();
    }

}```


//Log in page object:

public class logInPage extends DriverSetup{

    //Find the input email box in Login page
    @FindBy(id = "inputEmail")
    private static WebElement inputEmail;

    //Find input password box in Login page
    @FindBy(id = "inputPassword")
    private static WebElement inputPassword;

    //Find LogIn button in Login page
    @FindBy(id = "login")
    private static WebElement logInButton;

    public logInPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    //Confirm that you are on the Login page
    public static String confirmationHeader(){
        return header.getText();
    }

    //Method to enter email in email box
    public static void inEmail(String inEmail){
       inputEmail.sendKeys(inEmail + emailGenerator.randomEmailGenerator());
    }

    //Method to enter password in password box
    public static void inPassword(String PassInput){
       inputPassword.sendKeys(PassInput + passwordGenerator.randomPasswordGenerator());
    }
}```
````

This is the stack trace of the above code execution:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at logInPage.inEmail(logInPage.java:46)
    at test1.signIn(test1.java:15)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: can u please paste web element tag on which u want to click

Comment: @Ravi Yes, so the tag is: ``` <i class="ico fa fa-lock"></i> ``` URL: https://phptravels.com/demo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U are getting NPE(Null pointer exception) on line

```
loginButton.click();
```

it means you are doing some operation on object which got a null value and in this case it is none other than your loginButton

now the question comes up, Why login button is null when you are initialising it with

```
@FindBy(className = "ico fa fa-lock")
static WebElement loginButton;
```

it is possible because of web driver is not able to find this element and hence it is null

try following suggestions

```
public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

and if this does not work try with single class name like this

```
@FindBy(className = "ico")
private WebElement loginButton;

@FindBy(className = "login")
List<WebElement> buttons;
```

and while clicking like this

```
buttons.get(0).click();
```

else try with javascript click direct, it should surely work

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0].click()");
```

Comment: Nope, still no luck!

Comment: can u try this className = "login"

Comment: @PeterR Can you try with javascript click , the last line in edited answer by replacing your loginButton.click() with this

Comment: @PeterR Try javascript click

Answer (score 1):

Please check line number 55 in HomePage.java

It says

```
loginButton.click();
```

Nullpointer is because `loginButton` is null, probably because it is not initialized.

Most probably because it is not able to find the element by the classes that you have mentioned.

You might want to use '.' in front of the class names

Comment: can you please elaborate on you answer, particularyl when you said "Nullpointer is because loginButton is null, probably because it is not initialized."?

Comment: the annotation @FindBy, is going to find the login button. however, when you execute and the classes that you are looking for are not found on the page, the loginButton object is not being initialized.

Comment: And when you call a method on the null object, you get a Null Pointer Exception

Comment: You may upvote the answer, if I was able to help :-)

Comment: +1 for quick response to query, but when we use @FindBy(className="something") we don't need to use '.' as prefix

Answer (score 1):

`loginButton` is `null` because the locator you specified didn't match anything. `className` takes one class as parameter, you used three. To use more than one class you need to use `cssSelector`

```
@FindBy(css = ".ico.fa.fa-lock")
static WebElement loginButton;
```

Or `xpath`

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class='ico fa fa-lock']")
static WebElement loginButton;
```

Don't forget to initialize it `PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply to my query. This realtes to this URL: https://phptravels.com/demo/ Which when you use the dev tools to check this button, this is the name of the class "ico fa fa-lock".

Comment: @PeterR As I wrote in my answer it's not one class, those are 3 classes: `ico`, `fa` and `fa-lock`.

Comment: @PeterR Add to your question the stackrace and the `driver` and `PageFactory` initialization.

Comment: something like this? <b/> ```public HomePage (WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);

        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); //page instantiation

    }

  public void logInBut(){
        loginButton.click();

  }```

Comment: @PeterR Yes. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, it still did not work. PS: where can i do what you recommended "Add to your question the stackrace and the driver and PageFactory initialization"?

Comment: @PeterR Tou can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55493161/edit) button under the question. Post your updated code and stacktrace.

Comment: Driver set up, stack trace and log in page object added as you recommended.

Comment: upvoting for suggesting xpath approach

Answer (score 1):

Try the follwoing code.

```
@FindBy(className = "login")
static WebElement loginButton;
```

Or

```
@FindBy(xpath ="//a[@class='login']")
static WebElement loginButton;
```

Comment: @PeterR : I am able to click on the login button the link you have shared to OP.Strange.

Comment: Really? Can you share your code snippet here, showing it working, please?

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @Ravi, the Answer to my query is the below:

```
public class HomePage extends DriverSetup{

    @FindBy(className = "login")
    private static List<WebElement> buttons;

    public HomePage (WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

  public static void logInBut(){
      ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0].click()");
  }
}
//Trying with javascript click because of environment issue driver was not able to find elements with @FindBy, hence the web element was null and it was throwing NullPointerException

//If you need to read through to understand please see the comments and read @Ravi's comments in particular!
```